# how can i displaying more images using instagram API

Tags: ios, json, api, instagram, collectionview

currently i'm doing a practice project using instagram API. I got stucked about how can i view more images rather than 20 images by default using instagram API on user recent media. I believe there was something should i do with pagination when instagram return that value from my api call. Below is JSON which i got from instagram.

```
pagination =     {
"next_max_id" = "730184174375812259_19769622";
"next_url" = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/19769622/media/recent?access_token=16587801.7ce2ffe.f1ccd00d481c4858a2416d8983fe66f5&max_id=730184174375812259_19769622";
};
```

with this JSON data how can I implement like a real instagram app which means when I scrolling down to the bottom in my collection view,the 'next url' from JSON data got called and load a new images from this data? thanks for advance. cheers

p/s: below i attached my app screenshot for better understanding.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/haxSo.png